# mksh complete when moving to parent directory

Tags: autocomplete, mksh

I just installed the mksh and don't know how to solve one litte problem I have. When trying to change directory to the parent directory mksh does not complete when pressing "tab". Let me visualize:

```
$ cd .."tab"
```

will not end in

```
$ cd ../
```

What needs to be added to the mkshrc in order to get this feature?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: looks like a bug in mksh.  maybe try ksh93 instead. or bash.

Comment: Presumably that's not done because it's pointless: `../` and `..<TAB>` require the same number of keypresses. Even zsh doesn't complete `..` to `../` by default (though being zsh it has an option to enable it).

Comment: @Gilles Well, pointless is relative. I have a german keyboard and pressing "/" requires shift+7 whereas "tab" ist just "tab".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tab completion uses globbing internally. In `mksh` (and possibly other Korn Shell variants), `.` and `..` are *never* matched in globbing (to prevent accidents with `rm`, mostly).

Using a German keyboard is unfortunate, otherwise I’d say I’m with @Gilles on this… (I switched from de to us layout and don’t regret it, personally). But this does mean that there is nothing you can do to make `mksh` tabcomplete `..`.

If you need it often, you could use this:

```
function .. {
    cd ../"$1"
}
```

Unfortunately, this would *still* not allow tab-completing through it. So, <kbd>Shift-7</kbd> or switching kezboard (spelling intended) layout is the way to go.

Disclaimer: I’m the [mksh](/questions/tagged/mksh) developer.

Comment: Well, although I'm not happy with it I guess I'll have to accept it. Still, thanks for the reply.

oh, and +1 for kezboard ;)